# Prefer implicit rows instead of columns when using "grid-auto-flow: column"

Tags: css, css-grid

I don't suppose there is a solution for this, perhaps it's something I should post as a feature request with the browser makers?

My problem is I want my elements to flow in a column direction:

```
[1][3]
[2][4]
```

So I write the CSS:

```
.selector {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr:
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Now, if there are more elements *I want it to automatically generate more rows*, like this:

```
[1][4]
[2][5]
[3][6]
```

But *instead, the Grid generates more columns*, like this:

```
[1][3][5]
[2][4][6]
```

It would be helpful if I could say something like:

```
grid-auto-columns: none
```

Which would tell grid "don't generate more columns than I have explicitly told you to", and the only alternative it would have would be to generate more rows instead.

Comment: this is what `columns` is made for: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that property. Would be nice if I could use `grid` in this way though, becasue `grid` has other useful features that `columns` don't. Anyway, I might see if I can make a feature and see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick solution:** Use css [Multi Column Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout) rather than using with `column-count: 2;` on the container and `display: inline-block` on the cards(to avoid breaking across columns.). See MDN's [example for demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout#columns_and_fragmentation)

It achieves

```
[1][4]
[2][5]
[3][6]
```

---

**Long Answer:**

You should note that [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) represents the size of implicit grid columns. So `grid-auto-columns: none` would rather make sense as the new divs getting hidden into 0px wide implicit columns -- which doesn't happen either because `none` is not a valid value.

Now to the original question what *can be* achieved using grid is the following:

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
[5][6]
[7][8]
[9][10]
.
.
.
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p3sy8une/

Achieved using

```
grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
grid-template-rows:  repeat(auto-fill, 120px);
```

Your exact request cannot be achieved even using flexbox because  there's no way for the grid to know when to stop creating rows for a specific column and then start adding items in the next column. Both in the following are possible:

```
[1][5]        [1][6]
[2][6]        [2]
[3]           [3]
[4]           [4]
              [5]
```

w3c would have to put a second algorithmic step to put `floor(half)` or `floor(half) + 1` items in the first column and if there is a three column layout, then 1/3 in each column and 1/3 +- 1 in the last column.

Hope this helps, ciao.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
"grid-auto-flow: columns"
```

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example18/

Always in father element.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question - this problem occurs when you use "grid-auto-flow: columns".

If you take a closer look at how I want the layout to work vesus how it actually works I think you'll see what I mean.